# Is it possible to pass my value in node and express js by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

In this problem, I want to pass my values in express js so that it will written down in node js.
I am clicking a button which will be the demo here

```
<form action="/measure" method="POST">
    <button type="button" name="Add" > Add </button>
    <button type="button" name="Substract" > Subtract </button>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I did something like this in express js

```
const homePage = fs.readFileSync('./index.html')

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/html'})
    res.write(homePage)
    res.end()
})

var counter = 0;

app.post('/measure',(req,res) => {

    res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/html'})
    const {Add,Subtract,result} = req.body
    if (Add) {
        counter += 1;
    } else if (Subtract) {
        counter -= 1
    }
    res.write(homePage + `<h1>${counter}</h1>`)
    res.end()

})
```

But this doesn't do anything, based on my thought, the wrong about here is the button in index html which it doesn't pass anything...Have you guys any idea how I can pass the value in the express js? I've been searching since last night about it but couldn't find the right information, All I get is this link which is not my prefer since I am not focusing yet in database [LINK](https://gist.github.com/aerrity/fd393e5511106420fba0c9602cc05d35)

Comment: try adding a `value` attribute to your **button tag** like so:
`<button type="button" name="Substract" value="9001"> Subtract </button>` or you could also do something like:
`<input type="hidden" name="customvariable" value="customvalue">`

Comment: nah this ain't working haha.

Comment: @MYTH try to do it like this instead: `<input type="button" name"Add" >`

Comment: does the request get sent? does the code on the server run at all? do you get errors either in the browser console or on the server console? perhaps you've instantiated `app` incorrectly, can you show how that's done? i.e. are you using any body parser at all?

Comment: by the way, your code would POST to `/measure` with absolutely no request body anyway

Comment: yes, my point only here is to get the value of button..once I add or subtract something...thats all basically hahaha..you can see in the link that I give.

Answer (score 0):

A single button in a form can be represented as a `<button>` element. But if you want several buttons in a form, represent them all as `<input type="submit">`:

```html
<form action="/measure" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add"/>
  <input type="submit" name="Subtract" value="Subtract"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Depending on which button you press, you will get `req.body` as

- `{"Add": "Add"}` or
- `{"Subtract": "Subtract"}` or
- `{}`